# python modbus_tk: отсутствие ответа от slave (arduino)

Tags: python, arduino

Решая задачу обмена информацией по COM-порту с Arduino Mega 2560 с помощью modbus_tk столкнулся с проблемой отсутствия ответа от slave.
Пример кода:

```
import serial
import time

import modbus_tk
import modbus_tk.defines as cst
from modbus_tk import modbus_rtu

# PORT = 1
PORT = '\\\\.\\COM7'

def main():
    logger = modbus_tk.utils.create_logger("console")

try:
    #Connect to the slave
    master = modbus_rtu.RtuMaster(
        serial.Serial(port=PORT, baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', 
                      stopbits=1, xonxoff=0)
    )
    master.set_timeout(5.0)
    master.set_verbose(True)
    logger.info("connected")

    logger.info(master.execute(1, cst.READ_COILS, 0, 11))

except modbus_tk.modbus.ModbusError as exc:
    logger.error("%s- Code=%d", exc, exc.get_exception_code())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Вывод логгера:

```
2019-05-12 12:50:50,172 INFO    modbus_rtu.__init__ MainThread  RtuMaster 
\\.\COM7 is opened
2019-05-12 12:50:50,177 INFO    mbus_server.main    MainThread  connected
2019-05-12 12:50:52,178 DEBUG   modbus.execute  MainThread  -> 1-1-0-0-0-11- 
125-205
2019-05-12 12:50:57,178 DEBUG   modbus.execute  MainThread  <-
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/data/partner_live/mbus_server.py", line 50, in <module>
    main()
File "C:/data/partner_live/mbus_server.py", line 27, in main
    logger.info(master.execute(1, cst.READ_COILS, 0, 11))
File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\modbus_tk\utils.py", line 39, in new
    raise excpt
File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\modbus_tk\utils.py", line 37, in new
    ret = fcn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\modbus_tk\modbus.py", line 306, in 
    execute
    response_pdu = query.parse_response(response)
File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\modbus_tk\modbus_rtu.py", line 46, in 
    parse_response
    raise ModbusInvalidResponseError("Response length is invalid 
{0}".format(len(response)))
modbus_tk.exceptions.ModbusInvalidResponseError: Response length is invalid 0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

То есть, ответ нулевой длины. Потратил на это целый день. Пробовал отправлять запросы с помощью простейших SCADA, никаких проблем не возникало, регистры читаются без проблем, вид запросов и настройки идентичные.
Пробовал другие библиотеки, в том числе pymodbus, но ответ нулевой длины каждый раз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного абстрагировался от проблемы и внимательнее почитал форумы, например
[вот этот](https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/issues/73). Оказалось, что ардуино сбрасывается после открытия порта и прежде, чем посылать первый запрос необходимо добавить выдержку времени (не менее секунды), таким образом заработал следующий код:

```
import serial
import time

import modbus_tk
import modbus_tk.defines as cst
from modbus_tk import modbus_rtu

# PORT = 1
PORT = '\\\\.\\COM7'

def main():
    logger = modbus_tk.utils.create_logger("console")

try:
    #Connect to the slave
    master = modbus_rtu.RtuMaster(
        serial.Serial(port=PORT, baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', 
                      stopbits=1, xonxoff=0)
    )
    master.set_timeout(5.0)
    master.set_verbose(True)
    logger.info("connected")
    time.sleep(1)

    logger.info(master.execute(1, cst.READ_COILS, 0, 11))

except modbus_tk.modbus.ModbusError as exc:
    logger.error("%s- Code=%d", exc, exc.get_exception_code())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```